# How to avoid unwanted dll's in TFS build 2010

Tags: tfs, msbuild, automation

I am currently using default xaml to build my solution.

Right now, after every TFS build, my drop folder looks something like this:

```
{
 _publishwebsites
 x.dll
 y.dll
 x.unittest.dll
}
```

Is thereanyway to avoid all these dll's to be dropped during tfs build and just have _publishweb sites?

Answer (score 0):

This copying happens during TFS build in the section (sequence) "Revert Workspace and Copy Files to Drop Location" with invoking `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.CopyDirectory`:
[image]

One fast way to deal with what you are looking for is to change the `Source` into `String.Format("{0}\\_PublishedWebsites", BinariesDirectory)`. This will result to something like this:

```
Drop name (might want to change it to _PublishedWebSites)
{
  ... contents of _PublishedWebsites
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [change the configuration properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1hy4dhz.aspx). It is recommended to build your solution on the build server in the Release configuration. You can uncheck the Build option for the projects you don't want in this Release configuration.